# How can I restart the browser in the middle of a test?

Tags: webdriver

I need to verify some functionality around present the user with the option to pick up where they left off when they return to the site after having abandoned their cart. How can I close the browser and start it again in the middle of the test case so I can verify that the modal appears? I'm using RemoteWebDriver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the close command and then start a new instance

Comment: Hi am not qa mainly but working on big qa automation project, can you please post code snippet of what you mean how to start new instance , i know close .

Answer (score 2):

this code work for me

```
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();         // Clear Cookies on the browser
    driver.close();                             // Close a single browser window

    ProfilesIni firProfiles = new ProfilesIni();        
    FirefoxProfile wbdrverprofile = firProfiles.getProfile("default");          
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(wbdrverprofile);                 
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: If the accepted answer does not solve the problem for you, you need to ask a new question. You can link to this question if it's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two separate tests. One will put stuff in cart and close. Another test will start new browser, logs as same user, and checks if cart is in expected state. FOr extra credit you may start different kind of browser.

Comment: Isn't it bad form to have tests dependent upon other tests, marrying them to a specific order they must be run in? :(

Comment: Well yes it is bad - it was a solution for your problem. Solution is always compromise. Not sure why **a solution**  was worth downvote. I am waiting if someone has better one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to not do it; I spoke to my devs, and the same effect will happen if I navigate away and then back. But I'm still curious about how I would restart the browser if I had to.